# greatest in number a,b,c

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.7

```
def greater(a,b):
    if a > b:
        return a
    elif a==b:
        return "equal"
    else:
        return b

def greatest(a,b,c):

    if a>b and a>c:
        return 'a'

    elif a==b and a==c:
        return "equal"

    elif b > a and b > c:
        return b

    elif b==a and b==c:
        return "equal"

    elif c==a and c==b:
        return "equal"

    else:
        return c

bigger = greater(1,1)        
biggest = greatest(bigger,1,1)
print(biggest)


error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functions_execrise2.py", line 30, in <module>
    biggest = greatest(bigger,1,1)
  File "functions_execrise2.py", line 11, in greatest
    if a>=b and a>=c:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: You are trying to compare the string `"equal"` with `1`

Comment: Instead of `"equal"` you could return either `a` or `b`, since they have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

There is no question, but greater(1,1) probably returns "equal", so you are then calling greatest("equal",1,1), causing you to compare a string with an integer.